# Is this non-constant function periodic for every definable number?

Tags: functions, logic, periodic-functions

Given the set $\mathbb{D}$ which contains all definable real numbers. The definition must not be infinite long. E.g. it contains $12$, $-3$, $\frac{1}{12}$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\pi^2$, $i+e$, Chaitin's constant and many other numbers.

$$
f(x)=
     \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\text{if }x\in\mathbb{D}\\
       0 &\quad \text{else}
     \end{cases}
$$

Is it true that this function is periodic for every number which can be named / specified by anyone (which is equivalent to the set $\mathbb{D}$, or isn't it?)?

Thank you very much

Comment: I define $U$ to be the first undefinable number ...

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Then you need first to define a well-ordering of all the numbers ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, hmm, good point.

Comment: @user1952009: Otherwise "the first" does not necessarily make sense. For example "the first positive number" with the usual ordering does not define anything.

Comment: sorry thought was a comment addressed to Kevin. So if $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is any subset closed for finite addition/substraction (such as $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{R}_{definable}$, or $\mathbb{Z}+\pi \mathbb{Z}$) then $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ is closed for finite addition//substraction, and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in D$, $0$ otherwise is $a$-periodic for any $a \in D$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "periodic for every number"? Once we choose a specific number $x$, we don't have a function any more, just a value. The function is periodic, or not, so I don't follow what "for every number" means here.

Comment: Also, it is important to know that it is consistent with ZFC that *every* real number is definable in the language of set theory, so if that is what we mean by "definable" then we can't prove in ZFC that the function $f$ is nonconstant.

Comment: @CarlMummert : not an useful comment, since it is obvious most real numbers are not definable (in a finite number of mathematical words..), even if ZFC says the opposite... (or not)

Comment: @user1952009: perhaps it is obvious, but as this post explains, the usual reasoning to show there are undefinable numbers isn't sound: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb/44129#44129

Comment: @CarlMummert : given your previous comment, I don't think you understand very well what it says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some subtleties buried in the concept of "definable number". What exactly does it mean to you?

If you call a number "definable" if it satisfies a formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of set theory such that $\forall x\forall y(\varphi(x)\land\varphi(y)\to x=y)$ is true, then you run into the problem that "definable" is not itself a property that can be expressed in set theory. So your $\mathbb D$ may not exist at all. (Or it may, in an appropriately small model of ZFC, equal $\mathbb C$ itself, such that your $f$ is actually constant).

On the other hand, you *can* speak about definability in some particular restricted language, such as $(\mathbb C,\mathbb R,\mathbb Z,0,1,+,\cdot)$.
Then not everything you can describe using free-wheeling set theory will be definable, but the examples you give will, if the language is rich enough, which the one suggested above is. And in that case, then yes: Every definable number is a period for your function.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. Probably i should have written more detailed which definition of "definable number" i used. I only got information from this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number#Definability_in_models_of_ZFC